# Dropdown selection won't return data from second database

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, dynamicform

I am having several issues with a web based dynamic form that I am building.

My most frustrating problem at the moment, is that I can get a manufacturer database to populate the first, `#bodyman` dropdown, but I then need that first dropdown to populate a second, `#bodytype` dropdown based on the `#bodyman` dropdown selection, and then a *third*`#bodycolor` dropdown based on the selection from the `#bodytype` dropdown.

At the moment I'm trying to work through it step by step and I just cannot get it to return the products from the database.  I am using a combination of PHP, AJAX, and Javascript to run it, but this may not be the best way.  The final result is meant to be on an intranet site.

The "include "config.php" code is included in the header and seems to be functioning properly because the manufacturer dropdown is showing the correct options.  Watching the variables, it looks like `bodyman_id` is returning a correct value for the manufacturer input.  I just get the feeling it's not working because of some mistake on my end and can't seem to figure out why it's not working properly.  I have the database currently set up so that the manufacturer IDs are numbers and then the paver type has an ID column that lists the corresponding manufacturer number to the paver.  If there is an easier or better way to dynamically call info in this way, I'm open to it, this is just a way that I know has worked before.

This is the source code I currently have:

```
 <?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hardscapemfr where Pavers IS NOT NULL AND Pavers<>'';";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->get_result(); 
?>
            <label>Manufacturer</label>

            <select id="bodyman" onChange="getPavers(this.value);">
                <option value="0">N/A</option>
                
             <?php
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                
                    $id=$row['ID'];
                    $name=$row['Pavers'];

echo "<option value=".$id.">".$name."</option>";
}?>;
            </select>

        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <label>Paver Type</label>
            <select id="bodytype" onChange="getColor(this.value);">
                <option value="0">Select Type</option>
                
                
                
             
            
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <label>Color</label>
            <select id="bodycolor" style="width: auto">
                <option value="0">Select Color</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <label>Orientation</label>
            <select id="bodyorientation" style="width: auto">
                <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                <option value="Running Bond">Running Bond</option>
                <option value="Herringbone">Herringbone</option>
                <option value="Circular">Circular</option>
                <option value="Basket Weave">Basket Weave</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Javascript

```
function getPavers (bodyman_id){
    
    var paverel = document.getElementById('bodytype');
    var colorel = document.getElementById('bodycolor');
    
    paverel.innerHTML="";
    colorel.innerHTML="";
    
    var paveropt = document.createElement('option');
    paveropt.value = 0;
    paveropt.innerHTML = '--Select Paver--';
    paverel.appendChild(paveropt);
    
    var coloropt = document.createElement('option');
    coloropt.value = 0;
    coloropt.innerHTML = '--Select Color--';
    colorel.appendChild(coloropt);
    
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("$_POST","ajaxfile.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        try {   
            var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        }
            catch (error) {
                console.log("Error parsing JSON:", error, data);
            }
            
            var len = 0;
            if(response != null) {
                len = response.stringValue;
            }
            
            if(len > 0){
                
                for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                    var id = response[i].id;
                    var name = response[i].name;
                    
                    var opt = document.createElement('option');
                    opt.value = "id";
                    opt.innerHTML = "name";
                    paverel.appendChild(opt);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    var data = {request: 'getPavers',bodyman_id: bodyman_id};
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

AJAX file

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';
    
    $postData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $request = "";
    if(isset($postData->request)){
        $request = $postData->request;
    }
    //Get Paver Type
    if($request == 'getPavers'){
        $bodyman_id = 0;
        $result = array();$data=array();
        
        if(isset($postData->ID)){
            $id=$postData->ID;
            
            $sql = "SELECT * from belgard where Pavers IS NOT NULL AND Pavers<>'';";
            $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param();
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                
                $id = $row['ID'];
                $name = $row['Pavers'];
                
                $data[] = array(
                "ID" => $id,
                "Pavers" => $name
                    
                    
                );
            }
        }
        
        
        echo json_encode($data);
        die;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a couple of questions and one suggestion:

If you look at the Network tab in your browsers developer tools, can you what response the request to `ajaxfile.php` is returning? Is it an error or maybe a successful response but with no data? That may tell you that the problem lies there.

As far as this part of `ajaxfile.php`:

```php
$bodyman_id = 0;
$result = array();$data=array();
       
  if(isset($postData->ID)){
     $id=$postData->ID;
```

It *looks like* you're checking if the post data from the request has a property named `ID` but you're JS is sending `bodyman_id` in the request body. Additionally, your SQL query in `ajaxfile.php` doesn't seem to be using the `ID` information, and I'd assume you'd have something like `WHERE ID = bodyman_id` or something along those lines. (and I know it's for an intranet, but be **VERY** careful about inserting user supplied strings in your SQL queries. Gives someone the opportunity to perform an SQL injection attack [that could drop the table](https://xkcd.com/327/) or something).

As far as your JS request, you could use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead of `XMLHttpRequest`. I think it brings a cleaner format for making a requests, like so:

```js
async function getPavers(bodyman_id) {

  // ... Here are all of your variable declarations.

  const getPaverData = await fetch('ajaxfile.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      request: 'getPavers',
      bodyman_id: bodyman_id
    })
  })

  const paverData = await getPaverData.json()
  paverData.forEach((paverData, index) => {
    const opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = paverData.id;
    opt.innerHTML = paverData.name;
    paverel.appendChild(opt);
  }) 
}
```

**DISCLAIMER**: I'm pretty sure that's fine, I didn't try running it.

You'll notice it's using `async/await` to make sure it doesn't run a synchronously, but that isn't required if you want it to run async (though I won't suggest that without testing it so there isn't any behavior I can't diagnose).

Lastly, you have just the file name in the request but it will be treated like a relative link (`https://yourdomain.com/current/url/ajaxfile.php`) and if the file isn't located there then the request will fail. You may want to change it to something more precise (`/uri/of/file_location/ajaxfile.php`), but if it's hitting the file correctly then it isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: It's looking like the ajaxfile.php response is not returning any data.  The only thing I see in the response is one empty line and a second line that just has [].  It looks like my problem is probably somewhere in there

Comment: Thanks makes sense. I'd consider looking at the things I noted there in the file, but at least you were able to find where the breakdown is in the request/response chain.

Comment: That was a huge help.  This morning I was able to start finding why it wasn't returning data, then work through a few errors to get it to return data and it's working at the moment.  Now to move on to solving my next several problems.